# How to auto-restart VSCode debugger whenever I change a file in Firebase Typescript project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a typescript Firebase project for which I'd like to `watch` and `restart` debugger on file change.

my current script to run dev server:

```
"debug:func": "firebase emulators:start --only functions --inspect-functions 9230",
```

launch.json:

```
{
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "name": "Attach",
      "port": 9230,
      "request": "attach",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "restart": true
    }
```

Whenever I make a change in `*.ts` file:

1. I need to compile it.. `tsc`
2. restart debugger (ctrl+shift+F5) in order to debug the program.

How can I automate both steps (1 & 2) whenever I make a change to ts file?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this combination of scripts:

- **build:watch** which would simply be `tsc` in watch mode, i.e. `tsc -w`
- **debug:func**: Your existing script
- **debug:watch**: `nodemon --watch out --ext js --exec npm run debug:func`

The `debug:watch` makes use of [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), which will start your `debug:func` script and restart it every time a `*.js` file changes in your `out` directory. That means that with `build:watch`, your TS files will automatically recompile whenever they change, which will trigger nodemon to restart your `debug:func`.

It also requires the `"restart": true` in your task you have, along with a static inspect port, which you also have.